# Where an uploaded image stored?

Tags: document, content-database, file-system

I need to know where an uploaded image usually stored ?  I can't find it in file system. Only what I've got after saving is some changes in AllDocs table of SP database. 
To be precise:

```
Id                                   SiteId                               DirName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          LeafName                                                                                                                         Level ParentId                             DeleteTransactionId                WebId                                ListId                               DoclibRowId Type SortBehavior Size        ETagVersion EffectiveVersion InternalVersion ContentVersion NextBSN              MetadataNextBSN      StreamSchema HasStream   BumpVersion UIVersion   Dirty ListDataDirty DocFlags    ThicketFlag CharSet     ProgId                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          TimeCreated             TimeLastModified        NextToLastTimeModified  MetaInfoTimeLastModified TimeLastWritten         SetupPathVersion SetupPath                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       SetupPathUser                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   CheckoutUserId DraftOwnerId CheckoutDate            CheckoutExpires         VersionCreatedSinceSTCheckout LTCheckoutUserId CheckinComment                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   IsCheckoutToLocal VirusVendorID VirusStatus VirusInfo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       VirusInfoEx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      MetaInfo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         MetaInfoSize MetaInfoVersion UnVersionedMetaInfo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              UnVersionedMetaInfoSize UnVersionedMetaInfoVersion WelcomePageUrl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   WelcomePageParameters                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            IsCurrentVersion AuditFlags  InheritAuditFlags UIVersionString                                               ScopeId                              BuildDependencySet                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ParentVersion ParentVersionString                                           TransformerId                        ParentLeafName                                                                                                                   CtoOffset Extension                                                                                                                        ExtensionForFile                                                                                                                 ItemChildCount FolderChildCount FileFormatMetaInfo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               FileFormatMetaInfoSize FFMConsistent ListSchemaVersion ClientId
------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----- ------------------------------------ ---------------------------------- ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ----------- ---- ------------ ----------- ----------- ---------------- --------------- -------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----- ------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------ ----------------------- ---------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------- ------------ ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------------- ---------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------- ------------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------ --------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------- ----------- ----------------- ------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------- ---------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------- ------------- ----------------- ----------------------------------
5E6A066A-8574-45E3-A1E1-B560C4B8DA02 BC873236-5BA0-4301-8225-64BC2C3EB805 MyTeamSite/PublishingImages/SitePages/Home                                                                                                                                                                                                                       InternerError.png                                                                                                                1     BB3A78E8-2DDF-463B-94A3-40A7D528BB21 0x                                 ACD5871E-515B-493E-865E-4224FA8721C8 A4D65844-134F-4293-ACFA-9B7D8CF577E8 5           0    0            27725       3           769              769             3              162                  100                  66           1           0           512         0     1             324         0           -2          NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2017-09-01 13:33:34.000 2017-09-01 13:33:45.000 2017-09-01 13:33:34.000 2017-09-04 11:25:18.000  2017-09-01 13:33:34.000 15               NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL           NULL         NULL                    NULL                    0                             NULL             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0                 NULL          NULL        NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0xA8A930310C00000094030000789C7552ED6E9B3014FD1F29EFD00718C1363601A46982906CA8EB362559D34D9590013758831861930489879F09591A75A9FCC3BEBE9FE79CBB573C567953263BCA0B76E452492FD874AA6ED878B4D7CE8AD692D57B564B2E76DE6AD9413201FA608CC01021154FFFB4294D73965545B3DDD2 541          3               NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL                    NULL                       NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1                NULL        NULL              1.0                                                           15EBFCE1-3895-4F2C-9465-C0793D3B1F0C NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL          NULL                                                          NULL                                 NULL                                                                                                                             NULL      png                                                                                                                              png                                                                                                                              0              0                NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0                      0             31                NULL
725C6131-B32F-445B-9D08-07D2859A80B9 BC873236-5BA0-4301-8225-64BC2C3EB805 MyTeamSite/PublishingImages/SitePages/Home/_t                                                                                                                                                                                                                    InternerError_png.jpg                                                                                                            1     5126E781-DCE5-418A-8436-81EF01DB7CD1 0x                                 ACD5871E-515B-493E-865E-4224FA8721C8 A4D65844-134F-4293-ACFA-9B7D8CF577E8 NULL        0    0            3130        3           769              513             1              162                  100                  66           1           1           512         1     0             326         0           -2          NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2017-09-01 13:33:34.000 2017-09-01 13:33:34.000 NULL                    2017-09-01 13:33:45.000  2017-09-01 13:33:45.000 15               NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL           NULL         NULL                    NULL                    0                             NULL             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0                 NULL          NULL        NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0xA8A930310C00000085000000789C2B2BC98C4FCBCF49492DCA2C49CD4DCE2FCD2BB1F20CAA31E0E52A03CA24969664E417590507D5047B3806B906F87BFA85C4C414571603D54254E4E6A764A665A6A62455E25305B1A1B83409BB5500E04B30AE                                                             97           3               NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL                    NULL                       NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1                NULL        NULL              1.0                                                           15EBFCE1-3895-4F2C-9465-C0793D3B1F0C NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL          NULL                                                          NULL                                 NULL                                                                                                                             NULL      jpg                                                                                                                              jpg                                                                                                                              0              0                NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0                      0             31                NULL
15A3E00F-8EE8-4C5D-8472-546513C8114D BC873236-5BA0-4301-8225-64BC2C3EB805 MyTeamSite/PublishingImages/SitePages/Home/_w                                                                                                                                                                                                                    InternerError_png.jpg                                                                                                            1     C43312F9-8CA5-43C5-B2BE-071964FDAF9C 0x                                 ACD5871E-515B-493E-865E-4224FA8721C8 A4D65844-134F-4293-ACFA-9B7D8CF577E8 NULL        0    0            26951       3           769              513             1              162                  100                  66           1           1           512         1     0             326         0           -2          NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2017-09-01 13:33:34.000 2017-09-01 13:33:34.000 NULL                    2017-09-01 13:33:45.000  2017-09-01 13:33:45.000 15               NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL           NULL         NULL                    NULL                    0                             NULL             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0                 NULL          NULL        NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0xA8A930310C00000085000000789C2B2BC98C4FCBCF49492DCA2C49CD4DCE2FCD2BB1F20CAA31E0E52A03CA24969664E417590507D5047B3806B906F87BFA85C4C414571603D54254E4E6A764A665A6A62455E25305B1A1B83409BB5500E04B30AE                                                             97           3               NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL                    NULL                       NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1                NULL        NULL              1.0                                                           15EBFCE1-3895-4F2C-9465-C0793D3B1F0C NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL          NULL                                                          NULL                                 NULL                                                                                                                             NULL      jpg                                                                                                                              jpg                                                                                                                              0              0                NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0                      0             31                NULL
```

For example I go to Home.aspx and click edit and after that upload an imege and save it. How I can retrieve this image ? I've already tried to fetch binary data as string, write bytes to a file. But unfortunatelly it wasn't successeful.

And also I find out some changes at DocStreams table (SP2013)

```
select s.*
from AllDocs d
     inner join DocStreams s on s.DocId = d.Id
where LeafName like '%MyImage%'

DocId                                SiteId                               Partition BSN                  Size        Content                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          RbsId                                                                                                                              Type ExpirationUTC
------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ --------- -------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---- -----------------------
725C6131-B32F-445B-9D08-07D2859A80B9 BC873236-5BA0-4301-8225-64BC2C3EB805 0         162                  4348        0x05640000000011240202FD760144842640994A7749B9DB9DB3230505240200A22808E12869144891DB06708622F74A00052402035DD7F71ED796EBB76E24F98F79DD08B5000524020502FD760144842640994A7749B9DB9DB3000000091502886400220000200E020000031632BA324E2E052400010D0D000524013E000020 NULL                                                                                                                               11   NULL
15A3E00F-8EE8-4C5D-8472-546513C8114D BC873236-5BA0-4301-8225-64BC2C3EB805 0         162                  28173       0x056400000000112402485D2C9589D23349BDEA3C0A31E5966F230505240200B7CA7DC2B5EAB04A95FFEFAC5048286600052402034835823D4A154FB56A001053AFB7D7990005240205485D2C9589D23349BDEA3C0A31E5966F000000091502004D03220000200E020000039C4C03BA324E2E052400010D0D000524013E0000 NULL                                                                                                                               11   NULL
5E6A066A-8574-45E3-A1E1-B560C4B8DA02 BC873236-5BA0-4301-8225-64BC2C3EB805 0         162                  28947       0x0564000000001124020044B3B515D60F4383F7151A171CB8FB2305052402002140656A38629A4693ACA5D0EB68F7DF0005240203DEBF9A95C79D65B96C535A2F1497082000052402050044B3B515D60F4383F7151A171CB8FB000000091502306503220000200E02000003CC6403BA324E2E052400010D0D000524013E0000 NULL                                                                                                                               11   NULL
```

Comment: What version of SharePoint? The schema has changed over the years -- and of course, you shouldn't be diving into the SQL tables given this is a live, production database.

Comment: It's SP 2013. Yes I know, but I have to )

Comment: You're out of luck. There is no method to take the binary stamp that I'm aware of from the AllDocStreams table and convert it to the output of the file.

Comment: But I have the DocStream table

Comment: why do you want this info ? You should not be touching the database. For any interaction with the uploaded image, we have API support available.

Comment: @GautamSheth you mean REST SP API ?

Comment: yes, we have REST, SSOM (server object model) as well as CSOM (client object model, c# and javascript)

Comment: @GautamSheth The essential reason why I need to use a SP database is an disaster. I have a backup of a whole SH machine(with SP database). And now I need to restore SP on a new host. Yes, I can use SP Rest Api for uploaing, creating etc, but first of all I need to retrieve the info (from SP database or  file system) which will be recreated. That why I need to figure out how it stores.